# Will the use of the built-in ORM in CF 9 increase db performance?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

How will it or how will it not?
Appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's like asking if programming language A is faster than programming language B. The fact of the matter is that you can write poor code with either of them, and you can write good code with either of them.

As Stephen says, ORM is about improving development productivity - you don't have to pay the productivity cost of context switching between application code and SQL; and in some cases it offers application performance boosters.

However, if you're looking to "increase db performance" then ORM is not a silver bullet. I don't think that one (a silver bullet) exists.

Nothing can beat well written code (be it ORM or SQL) that has been analyzed and optimized.

Answer (score 2):

Well no not really...

ORM is not about increasing the performance of your database. Its about how you manipulate that data on the application side.

It does have elements such as object caching built in which do help with performance of your *application*, but you still need to create a well structured and indexed database schema.